# NoSuchMethodError: getter length was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I was able to create an SQFLite db and run a query, however, I receive the noSuchMethodError when I try to display the results using listview.separated widget. Reviewed other similar stack overflow topics but not luck. Mistakes in code - creating local variable?

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

final dbHelper = DatabaseHelper();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Breeds> allBreedsList;

    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'My 1st App',
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Pets, Pets, Pets'),
            ),
        body: Center(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                  child: Text(
                    'query',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    print("Yeah, it works!");
                    {
                      _pullAllbreed();
                    }
                    Expanded(
                        child: ListView.separated(
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return ListTile(
                          leading: Text("${allBreedsList[index]}"),
                          title: Text("${allBreedsList[index].name}"),
                        );
                      },
                      separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(),
                      itemCount: allBreedsList.length,
                    ));
                  }),
            ]))));
  }
}

void _pullAllbreed() async {
  final allBreedsList = await dbHelper.breedList();
  print('querying all breeds now, please stand by');
  allBreedsList.forEach((row) => print(row));
  int breedCount = allBreedsList.length;
  print(breedCount);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: Move out `ListView.separated` from `RaisedButton` 
Step 2: Move out `List<Breeds> allBreedsList` from `build` 
Step 3: `MyApp` use `StatefulWidget` and call `setState(() {});` after `_pullAllbreed();`

```
onPressed: () {
        print("Yeah, it works!");
        _pullAllbreed();
        setState(() {});
      }),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DatabaseHelper {
  Future<List<Breeds>> breedList() {
    return Future.value(
        [Breeds(name: "a"), Breeds(name: "b"), Breeds(name: "c")]);
  }
}

class Breeds {
  String name;
  Breeds({this.name});
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

final dbHelper = DatabaseHelper();

List<Breeds> allBreedsList = [];

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'My 1st App',
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Pets, Pets, Pets'),
            ),
            body: Center(
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                  RaisedButton(
                      child: Text(
                        'query',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        print("Yeah, it works!");
                        _pullAllbreed();
                        setState(() {});
                      }),
                  Expanded(
                      child: ListView.separated(
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        leading: Text("${allBreedsList[index]}"),
                        title: Text("${allBreedsList[index].name}"),
                      );
                    },
                    separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(),
                    itemCount: allBreedsList.length,
                  ))
                ]))));
  }
}

void _pullAllbreed() async {
  allBreedsList = await dbHelper.breedList();
  print('querying all breeds now, please stand by');
  allBreedsList.forEach((row) => print(row));
  int breedCount = allBreedsList.length;
  print(breedCount);
}
```

Comment: Ah,  'setState', I see. Testing now. Thank you.

Comment: successfully duplicated results; issue resolved. THANK YOU!